# javascript_tag の中で url_for に入力された値をセットしたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

テキストフィールド内に数値を入力させて、それを元に ajax で GET したいです。

```js
<%= javascript_tag do %>
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input[id^="multi_entry_user_id"]').focusout(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "<%= j user_json_multi_entries_url(User.first, format: :json) %>",
      data: e.target.value,
      dataType: "script",
      callback: null,
      success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        console.log('hoge success:' + status);
      },
      error: function (data, status, xhr) {
        console.log('hoge error:' + status);
      }
    });
  });
});
<% end %>
```

`User.first` の部分をユーザの入力値にする方法をご教示願います。

Comment: `url: "<%= j user_json_multi_entries_url(" + $(e.target).val() + ", format: :json) %>"`でできないですか？

Comment: user_json_multi_entries_url はサーバサイドで変換されるため、できませんでした (>_<)

Answer (score 1):

とりあえず自己解決したので報告です。

まずは以下のような HTML を生成し、、、、

```html
<div class="col-sm-2" data-user-url="http://locahost:3000/multi_entries/user_json/999999.json">
```

以下の javascript で URL 文字列を加工するようにしました。

```js
var t = $(this).closest("[data-user-url]").data('user-url');
var url = t.replace("999999.json", e.target.value + ".json");
```

"999999" の文字列を置換しているところがイケてないですね...(>_<)